# Riemann integrability for a sequence of functions

Tags: riemann-integration

**Task:**

Let $f_n:  [0, 1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$, $n \in \Bbb N$, be a sequence of functions with

$f_n(x) := 1$ for $n!x \in \Bbb Z$, $0$ otherwise.

Show that $f_n$ is Riemann integrable.

**Question:**

We didn't do anything with Lebesgue, so I think this might work by induction, but I don't see where to start.

Comment: $n!x \in \Bbb{Z}$?  The $!$ seems out of place.

Comment: It's written like that in the task.

Comment: What's it mean?  I know of only two meanings:  factorial (as in $3! = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$) and unique (as in "$\exists !x$ such that...").

Comment: it is meamt factorial

Comment: I understand it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to prove that the number of points, where $f_n(x)=1$ is finite.

$f_n(x)=1$, when $n!x\in\mathbb{N}$.

$n!x\in\mathbb{N}$, when $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x=\frac{a}{b}: a, b \in\mathbb{N}, n!\equiv 0\pmod b$.

It is obvious that there is only finite number of $\frac{a}{b}\in[0;1]$, which satisfy these conditions. So, $f_n(x)$ is continious at all but finitely many points, thus, integrable.